# How to Specify Identity Column in Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to go with Linq2SQL first and get it to create sql db for me but when I was creating fields I realized I couldn't see any Identity feature or something on Properties window.

*What should I do? **What I am thinking is to create db like this way and then go to SQL DB and change the column to Identity.***

Here is the snapshot of the selected UserId column in Linq2SQL file.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's set as autogenerated, which is how linq-to-sql columns are normally represented.

Have a look at the generated .cs file and see what it looks like. In a file generated by sqlmetal, an identity column has this attribute:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(
    Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, 
    DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", 
    IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

Can you find anything similar in your file? Specifically it is the DbType that is interesting.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You mean Auto Generated means Auto Incrementing value or something?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I directly wrote `int NOT NULL IDENTITY` in the Server Data Type column. It didn't give any errors.